# Content scroll is not working when using ion-tabs in ionic 4

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I am not able to scroll the content in  while i am using

**Ionic 4 + Angular 7**

Its seems to halt the screen not able to scroll screen.

**dashboard.component.html**

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<ion-content scroll="true">
Dashboard
This is the test content    
</ion-content>
            <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="dashboard>
        <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="leave">
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer this late and more than an answer this is a workaround, but it might unstuck people so I will still leave it here :

Remove the "`<ion-tabs>`" tags.

I couldn't find an other way, but it's more of a workaround because it's those tags that should allow you to leave all the routing to Ionic.

I'd still welcome a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

i solved add `<ion-toolbar>` on my code, like this

```
    <ion-toolbar>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="video">
      <ion-icon name="videocam"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Video Learning</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="podcast">
      <ion-icon name="musical-notes"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Podcast</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: This worked for me. You don't have to put the whole thing inside `ion-content` which makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in release [1.2.4](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.2.4) of ionic framework, please update your ionic.

This is a common fix, edit `scss/_scaffolding.scss`:

```
  &.pane {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

You can also try :

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Or a native scroll :

```
<ion-scroll direction="xy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"> </ion-scroll>
```

> I had the same issue, and I noticed that if I added `overflow-scroll=false` the scroll works and with `true` is doesn't

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="dashboard>
        <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="leave">
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-footer>
```

You must added ion-footer